# nginx rewrite rule is catching more than it should

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I've set up a rewrite rule as follows:

```
rewrite ^(www\.)*mysite\.com(/)*(index\.php)*$ /texts/mysite.com_page_24.html last;
```

It should only catch calls such as:

```
www.mysite.com
www.mysite.com/
mysite.com
mysite.com/
www.mysite.com/index.php
```

But it also catches calls such as:

```
mysite.com/index.php?option=com_correct&task=view&id=5&Itemid=30
```

Why am I getting this weird behaviour? the `^` and `$` signs clearly indicate start and finish.

EDIT:

looking at the log file when requesting an inner link that I don't want to catch gives:

```
"GET /mysite.com/index.php?option=com_correct&task=view&id=5&Itemid=30 HTTP/1.0" 200 118 "-" "-"
```

After further investigation it seems nginx is avoiding the arguments and acts as if it's the same page. How can I set nginx to not avoid the arguments and act as if they were different pages?

Answer (score 0):

Yea like you found out already, rewrites don't affect the query string, you need to handle the `$args` string, simple method would be putting your rewrite inside an if condition that says the args are empty, try something like this

```
if ( $args = "" ) {
    # your rewrite
}
```